# Replace a character at N position in a string

Tags: sql-server, string, replace

I want to replace a character at N position in a string. This my query:

```
SELECT code FROM tablecodes
```

The result is 3 rows:

```
AXGETYTRTFYZUFYZFFFDIZEG
GFYZUFYZFAXFCDIZAX
ZUFYZGEFYFAXFFIXZRA
```

I can't figure out how to replace the last 'Z' character on each row with 'A'. I want the result to look like this:

```
AXGETYTRTFYZUFYZFFFDIAEG
GFYZUFYZFAXFCDIAAX
ZUFYZGEFYFAXFFIXARA
```

The 'Z' character is always in the same position (length of the string - 3)

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**Stuff**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188043.aspx) Function

**Example:**

```
SELECT Stuff('AXGETYTRTFYZUFYZFFFDIZEG', Len('AXGETYTRTFYZUFYZFFFDIZEG') - 2, 1, 'A')
```

`Select` query should be like

```
Select Stuff(code, Len(code) - 2, 1, 'A')
```

Answer (score 1):

to replace any character at particular position you can use stuff function

```
SELECT STUFF('XYZABC', CHARINDEX('A', 'XYZABC'), 1, '#')
```

as per your question here is the solution.

```
DECLARE @stringTable AS TABLE(STRING VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @stringTable
VALUES('AXGETYTRTFYZUFYZFFFDIZEG'),
      ('GFYZUFYZFAXFCDIZAX'),
      ('ZUFYZGEFYFAXFFIXZRA')

SELECT STRING AS [Old String], 
       STUFF(STRING, LEN(STRING) - CHARINDEX('Z', REVERSE(STRING))+1, 1, 'A') AS [New String]
FROM @stringTable


 --------------------------------------------------------
|       Old String          |      New String            |
 --------------------------------------------------------
|  AXGETYTRTFYZUFYZFFFDIZEG |  AXGETYTRTFYZUFYZFFFDIAEG  |
|  GFYZUFYZFAXFCDIZAX       |  GFYZUFYZFAXFCDIAAX        |
|  ZUFYZGEFYFAXFFIXZRA      |  ZUFYZGEFYFAXFFIXARA       |
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

A few ways you could do it, one way would be:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/af25d/2

```
select left(code, len(code)-3) + 'A' + right(code, 2)
from tableCodes
```

note this is not doing any sort of validation that the string is long enough to perform the operations - so be careful.

Wasn't exactly sure if you would "always" have a Z as the third to last character in the string, so if you needed to check that additionally prior to making the replace you could do:

```
select 
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(code, len(code)-2, 1) = 'Z' 
        THEN left(code, len(code)-3) + 'A' + right(code, 2)
        ELSE code
    end AS code
from tableCodes
```